# Replacement for mplayer?

Tags: command-line, sound, mplayer

I'm looking for a replacement for mplayer. mplayer is a audio player for the console. It works just fine when I use it like so:

```
 mplayer /path/to/audio.mp3
```

But when I start it in the background I get this error message:

```
 :~$ mplayer /home/.alarm-sounds/alien1.wav &
 [3] 15451
 :~$ MPlayer svn r34540 (Ubuntu), built with gcc-4.7 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
 mplayer: could not connect to socket
 mplayer: No such file or directory
 Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.
```

I'm trying to write a little alarm script because I want to practice some modified version of pomodoro.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[From the manual](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/faq.html#idp11063536):

> **Q:** How can I run MPlayer in the background?
>   **A:** Use: `mplayer options filename < /dev/null &`

The redirect (note it's an input from `/dev/null`) is critical. `mplayer` is expecting input.

So in my case, the following works:

```
mplayer -nolirc ~/Music/Aqua/Aquarium/Aqua\ -\ 03\ -\ Barbie\ Girl.mp3 < /dev/null &
```

This is a shorter variation:

```
cat 0 | mplayer ~/Music/Aqua/Aquarium/Aqua\ -\ 03\ -\ Barbie\ Girl.mp3 &
```

Comment: That doesn't work either. I've tried it. Same LIRC error.

Comment: @Seth The LIRC notice is not a terminal error and passing in `-nolirc` will stop it from showing.

Comment: works just fine.

Comment: @Oli That's odd because it DID NOT work for me...

Comment: @Seth Try `mplayer [file] </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &`

Answer (score 6):

If you're just dealing with wavs, you can use `paplay`.

For mpeg playback you'll need something else. You could mess around manually decoding it and piping that back around into `paplay` but one alternative to `mplayer` is `mpeg321`:

```
mpg321 ~/Music/Aqua/Aquarium/Aqua\ -\ 03\ -\ Barbie\ Girl.mp3 &
```

And now *that's* playing. Great. I need to pick a better example when I do this stuff.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `cvlc`, the commandline version of vlc.

```
cvlc ~/Music/pathToSomeAlbum/someSong.mp3 &
```

If you want to hide all of the output as well as run it in the background use this neat trick:

```
cvlc ~/Music/pathToSomeAlbum/someSong.mp3 2>&1 > /dev/null &
```

That will route all the output into `/dev/null`.

Answer (score 1):

The lirc message can be avoided completely by adding the following to *$HOME/.mplayer/config*:

```
lirc=no
```

Unless of course you actually use a remote control...